# How to turn off :hover with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to completely turn-off hover event for an element with CSS?

My use case:

I have a list of products made of `<a>` elements. I do not want hover event to change anything on page to maximise frame rate on page scrolling.

---

I can write

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    ...
}
```

But is there a way to turn :hover completely for the element, so I do not need to override styles?

Comment: Nope....you're just out of luck.

Comment: Perhaps you can hide anchor tags and just use its href attribute in JS using window.location.

Comment: By turning it off completely, are you not overriding the styles anyways? And in a way that you can not add styling to that element type elsewhere on the page in the future if you wanted to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the same style for the normal and hover effect. That way the link will have the same style when you hover it, as when you don't.

You don't disable it, but it works.

```
a, a:hover {
   ... your style here ...;
}
```

Comment: This beats `pointer-events` simply because it will work on all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Found an answer I was looking for.

```
.disable-hover,
.disable-hover * {
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

It disables all hover events for an element.

Comment: Pretty neat. Be careful of [browser support though](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events)